# Jenkins build parameters

Tags: java, maven, ssh, jenkins, jelly

> I am trying to pass the build parameters to the PUBLISH OVER SSH plugin in Jenkins ,passing the build parameter to username field.
>   But instead of taking the username parameter value it simply takes ${username} and prints the same in console output.
>   SSH: Creating session: username [${USERNAME}]
>
> So i thought of modifying the existing code.
>   The jelly for username can be found here -

https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/jenkins/plugins/publish_over_ssh/BapSshCredentials/config.jelly

Is there a way this field can take parameter?